How to fetch the transaction amount from Arbiscan using Node.js
I am facing challenges when I try to fetch the transaction amount from Arbiscan (using Arbiscan API).
I want to fetch the transaction amount of my latest transaction using Node.js. The following Javascript code fetches the latest transaction hash:
const API_KEY = 'API_KEY ';
const WALLET_ADDRESS = 'WALLET_ADDRESS';

async function fetchFromAPI(url) {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error(`HTTP error! status: ${response.status}`);
    }
    return await response.json();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('API Fetch Error:', error);
    return null; 
  }
}

async function getLatestTransactionHash(apiKey, walletAddress) {
  const url = `https://api.arbiscan.io/api?module=account&action=txlist&address=${walletAddress}&startblock=0&endblock=99999999&page=1&offset=1&sort=desc&apikey=${apiKey}`;
  const data = await fetchFromAPI(url);
  return data && data.result && data.result.length > 0 ? data.result[0].hash : null;
}

async function main() {
  const latestTransactionHash = await getLatestTransactionHash(API_KEY, WALLET_ADDRESS);
  if (latestTransactionHash) {
    console.log('Latest Transaction Hash:', latestTransactionHash);
  } else {
    console.log('No transactions found or error fetching transactions.');
  }
}

main();

How can I modify the code to fetch the transaction amount of the latest transaction hash?
Thank you in advance!
